# Binary Sort vs. Insertion Binary Sort vs Insertion Sort

Tags: sorting, insertion-sort

I was asked to explain binary sort during an interview. Well, I didn't know the answer. After did some research online. I am really confused about the term Binary Sort, Insertion Binary Sort and Insertion Sort. Are they the same thing?

Comment: It would appear that an insertion sort involves linearly searching for the insertion position, whereas a binary insertion sort involves using a binary search within the sorted region to determine the insertion position. Not clear on the third.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful, et al.: No, the question does not already have an answer, since none of those "6 answers" authoritatively answers the question.  The accepted answer gives no definition for the term "binary sort" at all, that the answers that do are conflicting and do not refer to any published work to substantiate the use.